# publish war file to Azure Web Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, war

At first I want to mention, I did try some articles and also tried to get help for existing question/answer regarding deploying the war file to Azure web app but I didn't really got any where. I am new to it but also existing support either was in complete or very old.

I have created an App Service in Azure to host the war file. For my app service, I have selected Java 17 on Linux. For server stack selected 'Java SE'.  (I also created another web app with that uses TomCat instead of Java SE server stack)

Then I wanted to publish the war file.  So here I need guidance steps/ instruction to publish the war file Azure web app.
[image]

Comment: This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-java?tabs=javase&pivots=platform-linux

Comment: Yes I have seen this article but it doesn't describe how I can upload war file to app service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deploy your WAR package to Azure App Service to run your Java web app using the Azure CLI, PowerShell, or the Kudu Publish API.

**Note**: It is not recommended of deploying `WAR`/`JAR`/`EAR` packages using ***FTP*** or **`WebDeploy`**.

Use `az webapp deploy` command to deploy a WAR Package:

`az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path ./<package-name>.war`

Refer to [Microsoft documentation - Deploy WAR/JAR/EAR packages to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-warjarear-packages) for detailed information.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have run the above command in Azure Cli and was able to upload my file. NOw I am getting a 404 issue for which I have already created a post and hopefully I can resolve the issue completely.   For those who are getting the same issue can visit the post  @  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179371/uploading-the-war-file-to-azure-web-app-404-error/72183558#72183558

Comment: Sure @Salma, thank you for giving the solution to the community members which is most helpful whoever faces these kind of error!