# uploading the war file to Azure web app, 404 error

Tags: tomcat, azure-web-app-service, war

In an attempt to learn and publish the war file to azure web app, I am using Azure Cli and publishing the war file.  I followed the below article from microsoft documents.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#with-curl

and I used this code:
[image]

when I checked the files in kudu. I do see the file is updated but the name has changed to app.war rather than what was provided in the cli command.

When I visited the site, it gave me 404. Prior to uploading the war file, when I visited the site it was an empty page and nothing else but now I am getting error.

My app service is using Java 17 on Linux and Tomcat is the server.

[image]

Below are the available files after I uploaded the war file

[image]

Update:
Although I access the kudu but it is not as usual as because I don't see debug console.

[image]

Comment: What is the url you are trying to access ? Remove `/` at the end of teh url and check once

Answer (score 1):

In the off chance someone is attempting to deploy Spring Boot as a WAR file, the following applies to **deploying Spring Boot applications as WAR**. The CLI commands remain universal, however. Also note, since one would no longer using the embedded Tomcat server, must deploy to Java Tomcat, not Java SE.

Firstly, in my pom file I verified the following:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope><!-- THIS LINE MUST BE PRESENT -->
</dependency>
```

And in my code, I extended  SpringBootInitializer:

```
public class DwBootJarApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DwBootJarApplication.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DwBootJarApplication.class, args);
}
```

And finally, from command line in project root, to configure pom for Azure:

> mvn com.microsoft.azure:azure-webapp-maven-plugin:2.2.3:config

and to deploy:

> mvn package azure-webapp:deploy

This is not the only way to deploy, but it is what I find most convenient and is "officially" recommended for development stage of activities.

One final note, it is considered best practice to "pin" Java / Tomcat minor versions to a specific version and not auto update.